# @EnvironmentObject being tracked multiple times when passed into multiple controllers?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a view that checks if user is authenticated. If yes then Mainview().Environmentobject(AuthService()). If no then AuthView().Environmentobject(AuthService()). In my AuthService I have a init that checks for userSession. When the user is signed in i get two prints from the init section. when i log out and log back in i get 2 prints. If i log out again and log back in it becomes 4. Seems like AuthService being passed as an envrionmentObject is having multiple instances all tracking the same thing.. is this intended? I want one AuthService to be like a StateManager...

Answer (score 0):

You can create one instance and keep it in property, like

```
let authService = AuthService()

...
var body: some View {
  if authService.authnticated {
     MainView().environmentObject(authService)
  } else {
     AuthView().environmentObject(authService)
  }
}
```

Comment: how do i pass that same instance of auth into another controller?

Comment: I declared a globalAuth.... and used that... idk if that's right tho...

Comment: What do you mean by `another controller`? In SwiftUI there are no controllers - only views. Anyway, `AuthService` is a reference type, so you can pass `authService` by (inject as) a reference anywhere needed.

Comment: yah sorry my terms are bad. So I declared it as a global variable and was able to pass one instance to all of the views that need it. If  I don't do that the init will get triggered each time

Comment: just wanted to know if that is good practice? I am new to swift.